# Prevent Tomcat6 from caching for an application

Tags: caching, tomcat6, web.xml

I have an application running in a Tomcat6. Can I prevent Tomcat from caching for this application by setting in the web.xml? if yes, how?

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for all applications in the context.xml:

http://daveharris.wordpress.com/2007/07/09/how-to-configure-cache-control-in-tomcat/

I don't know how to do it just for one application.